# PySpark Oracle sequence generation using JDBC.Read

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, pyspark

Was trying to generate the ***sequence*** in Oracle for the records via PySpark JDBC read.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
if __name__ == '__main__':
        spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local")\
                            .appName("Seq_num")\
                            .getOrCreate()

        jdbcDF = spark.read \
                    .format("jdbc") \
                    .option("url", "URL") \
                    .option("dbtable", "(SELECT SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL) qry") \
                    .option("user", "USER") \
                    .option("password", "PWD") \
                    .load()

        jdbcDF.show(2)
```

This gives me an error

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o50.load.
: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here
```

The alternative was to have the above run using the `cur.execute(query)` which would provide me with tuples.
Is there any other way to achieve the above so that I can save time in converting tuples to Dataframe.